# Ionic 2: doInfinite() is being called if list does not have data

Tags: ionic2, infinite-scroll

When list does not have any item in it and if I scroll the content, the doInfinite() is being called.

I'm only facing this problem on IOS.

Here is the relevant code.

.ts file has:

```
doInfinite(infinite){
    setTimeout( ()=> {
      infinite.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

template file has:

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" threshold="100px" #infiniteScroll>
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Problem: When I scroll the content area, the doInfinte() method is being called.

`P.S.` We have not have any item on the screen.

Do anyone have workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want infinite scroll to be disabled when you do not have any data.

Check [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#input-properties)

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" threshold="100px" #infiniteScroll [enabled]="isEnabled">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

You can set `isEnabled` to true or false based on whether data is available in the component.

Second option is using [`enable()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#enable) function.

Use `ViewChild` to get the `InfiniteScroll` reference in your component:

```
 @ViewChild('infiniteScroll')infiniteScroll:InfiniteScroll;
```

and call

```
this.inifiniteScroll.enable(false);
```

when required.

Comment: Thanks Suraj but why content area is scrolling on IOS if we does have the content? It is not scrolling on Android. Do you have any idea?

Comment: scroll functionality is set in ion-content itself.. Will have to see the code.. html and relevant css